# Different style for most recent article

Tags: posts, loop

I'd like to make my most recent article display a large with a larger thumbnail and with more content, while the rest of the posts in the loop show a small thumbnail and only the title with no content.

Is there a way I can do this in one `while(have_posts())` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the built in counter `$wp_query->current_post` within the loop:

```
<?php
while( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();

    if( 0 == $wp_query->current_post ):
        // this is the first post in the loop, output larger size, full content, etc.
    else:
        // output regular size, the_excerpt, etc.
    endif;

endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no wordpress expert but could you use 2 loops one showing the latest post and one showing posts after in order to have the different CSS?

So loop for most recent ...

```
    <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1');
       while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ...
```

And the second loop (offsets the posts by 1)

```
    <?php $offset = new WP_Query('offset=1&showposts=5');
    while ($offset ->have_posts()) : $offset->the_post()...
```

You can change showposts=5 to show the number of posts you want in the remaining loop.